# O que Traceback significa?

Tags: python, terminologia, debug

Quando criando alguns programas básicos em Python, ocasionalmente me deparo com erros que trazem a palavra *traceback*, por isso me surgiu a curiosidade de descobrir o que *traceback* significa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É o mesmo que *stacktrace*, um termo um pouco mais usado em linguagens em geral. A tradução literal é rastreamento. Então serve para rastrear o que a aplicação está fazendo, mas de uma forma simples.

O código é sempre executado em uma pilha de chamadas de funções, ou seja cada função que é chamada é colocada nessa pilha.

Quando ocorre um erro o *runtime* da linguagem pesquisa essa pilha para encontrar todas funções que foram chamadas, o número da linha que cada função está executando naquele momento, se a informação estiver disponível (exceto a primeira, sempre mostra uma linha onde está sendo feita a chamada da próxima função), e eventualmente algumas outras informações, como o nome do arquivo, módulo, ou algo assim.

A pilha normalmente é mostrada na ordem empilhada, então o que foi chamado por último (está em cima da pilha) mostra primeiro. Ma em Python mostra na ordem de chamada.

Obviamente que o erro gerado mostra o que o causou, que é uma das informações mais importantes.

[Exemplo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace):

```
 def a():
      i = 0
      j = b(i)
      return j

  def b(z):
      k = 5
      if z == 0:
          c()
      return k / z

  def c():
      error()

  a()
```

Gera o *traceback*:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "tb.py", line 15, in <module>
>     a()
>   File "tb.py", line 3, in a
>     j=b(i)
>   File "tb.py", line 9, in b
>     c()
>   File "tb.py", line 13, in c
>     error()
> NameError: global name 'error' is not defined
> ```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Reflection/Traceback.py).

Ele é importante para saber o que deu errado e saber onde olhar para consertar o erro. É preciso aprender interpretar essas informações para conseguir depurar a aplicação.

A qualidade da informação depende do *runtime* da linguagem.

A única forma de evitar isso é não deixar a aplicação gerar um erro. Pena que algumas pessoas entendem que para isso é melhor capturar todos os erros antes da aplicação quebrar e mostrar o *traceback*. Quando o erro é de programação, ele é fundamental. Pode até fazer ele não aparecer para o usuário, mas essa informações não pode ser desperdiçada, ela precisa ser mostrada para o programador em algum lugar. Erro de programação só resolve se consertando o problema.

É possível fazer uma operação de *trace* mais detalhada que é possível fazer, independe de ter um erro gerado, serve para o mesmo propósito, mas é um mecanismo bem diferente, a começar por ser sob demanda.